# Dynamic method definition with GroovyDSL in IntelliJ

Tags: grails, ide, groovy, intellij-idea, dsl

I was trying to define a dynamic method using the GroovyDSL scripting capabilities in IntelliJ. The starting guide ["Scripting IDE for DSL awareness"](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/GRVY/Scripting+IDE+for+DSL+awareness) gives you a good idea on how to get started with this. The dynamic method definition in my DSL is more complex than the example though and I am not quite sure how to build this. You can imagine it working like [dynamic finder methods](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.4.1%20Dynamic%20Finders) in Grails except that you can combine an arbitrary number of criteria with a boolean `And` keyword in any order. All keywords are not defined in the class that I am invoking the method on but could be defined in the GDSL file. The method always starts with `submitTransactionWith`. Here's an example:

```
clientDSL.submitTransactionWithCriteria1AndCriteria2AndCriteria3(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

I started out with this but that only works for one criteria and doesn't take into account that you can combined multiple criteria in any order.

```
def ctx = context(ctype: "my.client.ClientDSL")

contributor(ctx) {
    ['Criteria1', 'Criteria2', 'Criteria3'].each {
        method name: "submitTransactionWith${it}",
               type: 'java.util.Map', 
               params: [args: 'java.util.Collection']
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there's special support for that kind of dynamic method. I'd also be interested in how the DSL for Grails is modeled internally in IntelliJ.

Comment: I've created an issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-81225

Answer (score 1):

The Grails DSL in located in `${idea.home}/plugins/GrailsGriffon/lib/standardDsls`

It would probably help you for your problem. They create string arrays of all the method name combinations ahead of time, and then just iterate through them in their contributor creating a method using the arrays of strings for names.

Comment: It doesn't look like they define dynamic finders in that GDSL but thanks for pointing me to it.